# Best approach to embed a video inside on-premises sharepoint team site (non-publishing site)

Tags: 2013, administration, sharepoint-on-prem, video, assets

We have SharePoint 2013 classic team site and it does not have publishing features enabled. now inside the team site we have a Discussion board list, and **i want to embed a video inside its body**,so users can play the video. but when i create a new discussion board list item, i did not get any web part or option to upload the video, as follow:-

[image]

now i do not want to enable the publishing features on this site as it will have many drawbacks on the current content. but on other site collections which have publishing features enabled i can get a web parts to upload the video, as follow:-
[image]

so inside a team site which does not have publishing features enabled, this how i can embed a video inside a discussion board list item's body, so users can play the video directly ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just verified on a test site and the option shows up without publishing. Please ensure site collection feature 'Video and Rich Media' is active in your site collection.

Comment: now i already have the "Video and Rich Media" enabled on my site collection...